# Rails app not restarting following deletion of solr folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
RAILS 3.2
```

In my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

The application was running fine, until I cleaned it up, and part of the process included deleting the app/solr directory.

In my config/sunspot.yml file, I have:

```
staging:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/staging
```

I ran:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then:

```
rm -Rf /home/app/solr
mkdir /home/app/solr
mkdir /home/app/solr/staging
rake sunspot:solr:stop
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start

screen -d -m sh -c 'RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rakesunspot:solr:reindex[500] > /home/installio/app/solr/indexing_out.txt'
```

The app/solr directory has in it the following structuere

```
pids/staging/sunspot-solr-staging.pid
data (empty directory)
staging (empty directory)
```

And I am getting the "something went wrong message).

From the sunspot-solr-staging.log:

```
SEVERE: Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are your error logs saying?

Comment: See the edit. I cannot find that .xml file